# Avoiding eval() function when using custom function

Tags: qgis, labeling, expression, qgis-custom-function

**CONTEXT**

I have several raster layers which overlap. I created a point layer with labels that represent different values for each of these raster layers. I created a function that

- lists all layer names in the canvas
- if the layer in the canvas is checked, its name is compared to a list string representing layer names that I would like to label.
- if they match, then the function returns a string that represents a string representing the field name.

When I use this function for labeling, I still need to use `eval()` to get the value I want to show as a label.

Is there a way to skip from using `eval()`?

The function is shown below:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', referenced_columns=[])
def raster_label(feature, parent):
    field_list = ["LAYER_A", "LAYER_B", "LAYER_C", "LAYER_D"]
    raster_layer_name_list = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
    field_to_show = ""

    # create a list with all layers in the canvas
    layers_list = []
    root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    for child in root.children():
        if isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
            get_group_layers(child)
        elif isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeLayer):
            layers_list.append(child.name())
        
    # iterate over all items in layer list ...
    for item in range(0, len(layers_list)):
        l = QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName(layers_list[item])
        node = root.findLayer(l[-1])
        # then identify if the layer is checked ...
        if node.isVisible() == True:
            # to compare agains the raster_layer_name_list ...
            for raster in range(0, len(raster_layer_name_list)):
                # returning then the corresponding field
                if l[0].name() == raster_layer_name_list[raster]:
                    field_to_show = field_list[raster]
                    break
            if field_to_show != "":
                break
        if field_to_show != "":
            break
    
    return field_to_show
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot avoid using `eval` as long as you return a field name (it is a string) to the expression area. It will be considered as a string in Expression Dialog.

But you can use the conditional `return` instead of `return field_to_show` as follows:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', referenced_columns=[])
def raster_label(feature, parent):
    
    #
    # previous lines
    #

    if field_to_show = "":
        return ""
    else:
        return feature[field_to_show]
```